# How can i debug android apps?

Tags: debugging

You may have more luck with IntelliJ IDEA android plugin (free community version has android support, but I'm not sure about scala, full version is available for 30 days)

Comment: you can refer this tutorial for how to debug using CharlesProxy
https://dogcomp.medium.com/setup-charles-proxy-to-intercept-https-traffic-of-android-emulator-591baba5d7ec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out with fiddler and charles proxy they are good for debugging